# What does a huge chi-square statistic mean?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, chi-squared

My chi-square statistic is approximately $2945.0945$. Is this supposed to happen? I followed the formula on [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chi-squared-test/#intuitive-explanation) website to a $T$. Could it be because my data is really large? Is there some kind of step I'm missing?

Here are my calculations
[image]

Comment: Looks right to me. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNT91qwyAUvhd8h0OvzCZWkzamF3uSkYFts1ZIolM7NsbefeckGx3CEb7z_R0_xZAK5JOPnyoXVzJnfsUmV66ccRaOGZ7g2ZjathIOxh4ktLW2Epqu3Uuod42RYDpLs94hx2jbSeiatueshOJG1OfbJNCp4mycjUaA7NUYLsJoBIePGFM4UtB9AY9glN6eq-2ieQ0JzuBnSG6-DCAoT1f9IiZhfFjDiBeJ92va0xWnq89vEuL72uZ-r1o2N5cG6idJhH1i8nMRG9y91Mj_-kbp8m8U2mNF8c-wqijh7_0AM4tgUA==&lang=python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $9$ degrees of freedom?  You should expect a number in the range 5 to 20, say.  A big values like this means the "null hypothesis" does not fit the data well.

Edited, after checking your calculations and rereading your comments. I get the same chi-squared value.  It means, your digit counts do not fit the $\log_{10}(1+1/d)$ formula.

As you have guessed, a large sample size will make the test statistic bigger, if the model is wrong or even just slightly wrong.  (You can see this if you artificially multiply all the counts by, say, 1000.  Then the test statistic will also be multiplied by 1000, too.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What is "the all" equal model? For the expected frequencies, I multiplied the expected probability (given by Newcomb's prediction for Benford's Law) by the total frequency.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for the help, that makes a lot of sense. I'm doing this for a math exploration and I'm so frustrated, I don't think I'm cut out for this at all.